# Redirect after the sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to redirect the user after the sign up by saving the referer in case when user came to sign up through clicking on any specific page. But its not working properly.

In my app controller

```
def save_referer
  unless user_signed_in?
    unless session['referer']
      session['referer'] = request.referer || 'none' 
    end
  end
end
```

In user model

```
def save_with(referer)
  referer = referer unless referer == "null"
  self.save
end
```

Here im saving it

```
if current_user.sign_in_count <= 1
  if current_user.save_with(session[:referer])
    redirect_to session[:referer]
  else
    redirect_to any_other
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In User model, I guess you are not explicitly referring the attribute correctly.

```
def save_with(referer)
  self.referer = referer unless referer == "null"
  self.save
end
```

Comment: Initally i did this but then i got undefined method `referer=' for #<User:0xc4a8bf0>

Comment: After Sign up, i have user profile completion step and im redirecting to referer after the profile completion and it is mandatory. Sometimes its redirecting to default-host page and sometimes its not even redirecting. It should redirect to referer page.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I take this strategy:

Anywhere I have a signup button I link to signup like so:

```
<a href="/signup?signup_refer=/current_path">Signup!</a>
```

Then in my signup's Action I do this:

```
def signup
  session[:signup_refer] = params[:signup_refer] if params[:signup_refer] # put the refer in a session
  redirect_to(signup_path) if session[:signup_refer] && params[:signup_refer] # this clears params if you want to keep your url nice an clean for the user
  # do signup stuffs
  signup_refer = session[:signup_refer] # get the refer info in a variable
  session[:signup_refer] = nil # clear the session before redirecting
  redirect_to(signup_refer ? signup_refer : "/default_post_signup")
end
```

I know it could be messy, but it totally works for me (well works in Merb, where it's "`redirect()` not `redirect_to()`) but you get the idea.

Comment: It looks very messy, Im using Devise for sign up. As i told i have 2 step sign up, after sign up i redirect user to fill up profile and it is mandatory, and i'm redirecting to referer page after saving the profile. My above code is fine but it often redirects to default host page. i don't know why?